# How to server control in MVC razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i am using MVC 4 with Razor Engine in my application,i needed to add the ASCX user control in partial view. But the question is How ?

Example :

```
FileName : PFDViewers.ascx
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PFDViewers.ascx.cs" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>-
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:textbox runat="server"></asp:textbox>


Razor view:

@html.partialView("PFDViewers.ascx")
```

Is this possible to add the ASCX controls to Razor view.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yohh ..

@`Html.Partial("_MyASCXPartial")`

Then add this

```
   <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>"%>
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:textbox runat="server"></asp:textbox>
```

Just trying to help.

Comment: exactly the same answer as i've already posted?

Comment: ooh .. im so shoorry .. but i haven't imitated yours .. maybe we just really had same answer and i didn't notice it ..

Comment: @scgough Or.. it takes 10 minutes to answer and they didn't notice you had answered *in the meantime*.  Maybe Anaiah started their answer *before* you?  Happens all the time. It's not like a copy+paste. Check the answer times.  (just says '1hour' now)

Comment: fair enough! I retract my statement. Apologies for any offence caused @Anaiah

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m .. Yeah I bet that was what happened.

Comment: and @scgough .. No problem .. PEACE yow

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this mix of webform and razor is considered very good practice.
That said, could you create a partial view in your shared folder which contains the ascx code?

So you would say this in your razor view:

```
@Html.Partial("_MyASCXPartial")
```

Then `~/shared/_MyASCXPartial.cshtml` would have your server control.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PFDViewers.ascx.cs" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>-
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:textbox runat="server"></asp:textbox>
```

Comment: its working for with out using any servercontrol,
if i use server controls not working and throw the below error,

 Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper